# How do I send current location data to another activity? (Kotlin)

Tags: google-maps, android-activity, kotlin

all good friends?

I need to send the current location data to another Activity.
How do I send current location data to another activity?
And to get this data in another Activity you have to use "getStringExtra"
I can get the data from the current location, but I can't send it to another activity. Could you help me, please?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?) = false

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val formatDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        val dataInicial = formatDate.format(Date())

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        btIniciarVisita.setOnClickListener {
            val situacaoIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SituacaoActivity::class.java)
          //  var dadosMapa = currentLatLng.toString()
          //  intent.putExtra("DadosMapa", dadosMapa)
            intent.putExtra("DataInicial", dataInicial)
            Log.i("TAG",dataInicial)
            startActivity(situacaoIntent)
        }


    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }

        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng)
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12.0f))

            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }

    private fun placeMarkerOnMap(location: LatLng) {

        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(location)
        map.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd better create some Location manager to get access from anywhere, data to another activity you can pass with Intent

Comment: you can pass individual parameters like lat,long along with intent or you can convert location object with Gson() as string and on another activity return back object.